# Structure of an if and only if proof

Tags: logic, proof, language, fitch

I am trying to get this proof to work out and so far I feel like I have the first part right but I'm stuck on how to get the A→B part.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very similar question with three answers: [Prove (¬P ∨ Q) ↔ (P → Q)](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/46774/29944)  Your question seems to be focused on the Fitch system and your approach to the problem seems to be different. I will only address how you might proceed without considering how you might do this in the Fitch system.

You are attempting to use disjunction elimination with the first line having ¬A v A. However, what you need to show is given A→B that you can derive ¬A ∨ B and then show given ¬A ∨ B that you can derive A→B.

Here is how it would be done with another proof checker. I include it to show what might work. You will have to adjust it to the rules and syntax of the proof checker you are using.

[image]

Note that one direction of the biconditional (if and only if) proof occurs on lines 1 to 9. The other direction occurs on line 10 to 17. On line 18, the biconditional (↔) is introduced.

The descriptions of the rules are given in the links below.

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Winter 2018. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to get this proof to work out and so far I feel like I have the first part right but I'm stuck on how to get the A→B part.

Begin by assuming A → B, then state LEM as a  Tautological Consequence to use disjunction elimination to derive ¬A ˅ B.  Also, your attempt needs to be tidied up, you have a few unecsessary steps and you seem to forget that the goal is ¬A ˅ B (rather than A ˅ ¬B as you have towards the end).

```
| |_ A → B            Assumption
| | ¬A ˅ A            Taut Con (LEM)
| | |_ ¬A             Assumption
| | |  ¬A ˅ B         ˅ Intro
| | ¬A → (¬A ˅ B)     → Intro
| | |_ A              Assumption
| | |  B              → Elim
| | |  ¬A ˅ B         ˅ Intro
| | A → (¬A ˅ B)      → Intro
| | (¬A ˅ B)          ˅ Elim
| (A → B) → (¬A ˅ B)  → Intro
```

---

Now, for the converse, you should assume ¬A ˅ B and derive A → B through ˅ elimination.  Assuming ¬A and A will derive B from explosion, while assuming B and A will derive B from reiteration.

Hence (¬A ˅ B) → (A → B).

---

Then use biconditional introduction to complete the proof.